# Which Linux shell command can completely remove a file from the system and make it unrecoverable?

Tags: linux, command-line, data-recovery, rm, shred

**Which Linux shell command can completely remove a file from the system and make it unrecoverable ?**

I have tied rm and shred but they have their limitations:-

```
rm --help
```

and see the information, you will see a note there like this

> Note that if you use rm to remove a file, it might be possible to
> recover some of its contents, given sufficient expertise and/or time.
> For greater assurance that the contents are truly unrecoverable,
> consider using shred.

this note suggests to use the **shred** command so do I did

```
shred --help
```

> Overwrite the specified FILE(s) repeatedly, in order to make it harder
> for even very expensive hardware probing to recover the data.

This seems like a good note and I was relaxed that my file will be removed completely now or at least will be harder to recover. and made my mind to use **shred** instead of **rm** from now but wait got this **CAUTION** in the end.

> CAUTION: Note that shred relies on a very important assumption:
> that the file system overwrites data in place.  This is the traditional
> way to do things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy this
> assumption.  The following are examples of file systems on which shred is
> not effective, or is not guaranteed to be effective in all file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied with
>   AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file systems that write redundant data and carry on even if some writes
>   fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file systems that make snapshots, such as Network Appliance's NFS server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS
>   version 3 clients
> - compressed file systems
>
> In the case of ext3 file systems, the above disclaimer applies (and
> shred is thus of limited effectiveness) only in data=journal mode,
> which journals file data in addition to just metadata.  In both the
> data=ordered (default) and data=writeback modes, shred works as usual.
> Ext3 journaling modes can be changed by adding the data=something
> option to the mount options for a particular file system in the
> /etc/fstab file, as documented in the mount man page (man mount).
>
> In addition, file system backups and remote mirrors may contain copies
> of the file that cannot be removed, and that will allow a shredded
> file to be recovered later.

at last I read a few blogs but could not find a command which does the job, can anyone suggest a better command than these two or a way to remove the file as I have some important credentials file which I need to remove completely?

Comment: What is the file system and what are its options?

Comment: Mine is ext4 file system @slhck

Comment: If this is an SSD then old data is erased using TRIM, so no need to shred.

Comment: TRIM is an option for SSDs, but there no guarantee of *when* the data might be truly unrecoverable. The drive controller might return nothing but zeros if you read that block, but you have no idea when the flash cell itself will be erased and a well equipped adversary with plenty of time and resources *might* be able to recover it (unrealistic but possible). If you 100% must guarantee that the file is not recoverable then your only option is physical destruction.

Comment: Otherwise you should look at attacking the problem from another direction. Full disk encryption will make *any* disk essentially unrecoverable in the event that the password or key is lost. If you have to handle sensitive data and want to know that it is unrecoverable then all you have to do is to overwrite the key. You'd end up with what appears to be a new blank disk or partition that needs formatting, but the old data is protected by the now lost key and should remain protected until such time as you finally overwrite it with new data.

Comment: why must it be unrecoverable?

Comment: @Mokubai - FDE does have one potentially critical vulnerability... the $5 wrench test! 8-D https://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: On U&L SE: [How can I be sure that a directory or file is actually deleted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63337/108618)

Comment: Also, there might be backups or snapshots that still contain the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either:

The **[Secure-delete](https://pkgs.org/download/secure-delete)** suite of tools

Or **[BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/)**

These articles provide a good overview of each one and their use:

https://www.unixmen.com/securely-delete-hard-drive-data-with-secure-delete/

https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-delete-your-data-securely-linux

I also strongly recommend reading [this section](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/shred-files-and-wipe-disks.html) of the BleachBit Docs for an excellent write-up on properly securing/deleting data in general... in short, for your use-case:

1. Shred the file/s ('srm' in secure-delete).
2. Overwrite all free disk space ('sfill' in secure-delete).
3. Ideally encrypt the data (e.g. credentials could be stored in a passwors keeper, like KeePassXC) and/or the entire drive/volume in future.
4. And in the end, mechanically destroy or degauss the drive (if it's that important to you).

Hope that helps.